# Rx Buffering With Variable Count

Tags: reactive-programming, system.reactive, reactive

I have a `IObservable<byte>` that I want to split into `IObservable<byte[]>`, presumably using a combination of Buffer(), Window(), Scan(), etc.

I'm having trouble finding the proper composition of Rx functions to handle my specific situation, though.  Most Q/A about the topic ends with the answer mentioning that you can pass in a test to see if the item (byte/char) is a delimiter, and break up the buffer that way.  My problem is that it's not just one byte that is a delimiter.  In my case I'm reading in 4 bytes which is the length, and then I want to buffer that amount from the following data as the return byte[].

One route I attempted was that I could make a `IObservable<int>` which represents the lengths of the packets, which some other user could use to break things up into buffered byte[]s.  Maybe something like:

```
IObservable<int> lengthsObservable = byteObservable
    .Buffer(4)
    .Select((b) => BitConverter.ToInt32(b.ToArray(), 0))
    ...
```

But this has the problem is I'm not sure how to insert the logic to skip the data after the int conversion.  How do I buffer 4, convert to int, SKIP that amount, then repeat the buffer (4), and continue?

I've toyed around trying to compose some solution with the API, but to no real luck.  My nuclear option is to create a very fiddly Scan() call with a very custom accumulator class, but I feel like there's a better more kosher way.

TLDR
Is there a common composition pattern that Rx veterans know of to Buffer() with a delimiter that is not just one unit?

Edit:
A more concrete example of the question would be splitting an `IObservable<byte>` with the output:

`0B 00 00 00 48 65 6C 6C 6F 20 57 6F 72 6C 64 12 00 00 00 54 68 61 6E 6B 73 20 66 6F 72 20 68 65 6C 70 69 6E 67`

And processing that into an `IObservable<byte[]>` with two array outputs:

`48 65 6C 6C 6F 20 57 6F 72 6C 64 // Hello world`

and

`54 68 61 6E 6B 73 20 66 6F 72 20 68 65 6C 70 69 6E 67 // Thanks for helping`

The initial `0B 00 00 00` is the length of the byte chunk that follows.  Immediately after them is another length `12 00 00 00`, with another byte chunk.

Comment: I find descriptions harder to understand than sample data and expected output. Can you please give us a sample stream of bytes and what the result you're looking for on those bytes?

Comment: Added a more concrete example at the end.  Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: Excellent explanation.

Comment: I suggest that you "create a very fiddly Scan() call with a very custom accumulator class".

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of a 'fiddly `.Scan()` call with a very custom accumulator class'. I don't think it's that awful. At least it abstracts nicely:

```
class AccumulatorState
{
    public AccumulatorState()
        : this(4, 0, true, new byte[0])
    {}

    public AccumulatorState(int bytesToConsume, int bytesConsumed, bool isHeaderState, IEnumerable<byte> accumulatedBytes)
    {
        this.TotalBytesToConsume = bytesToConsume;
        this.BytesConsumed = bytesConsumed;
        this.IsHeaderState = isHeaderState;
        this.AccumulatedBytes = accumulatedBytes;
    }

    public int TotalBytesToConsume { get; }
    public int BytesConsumed { get; }
    public bool IsHeaderState { get; }
    public bool IsComplete => BytesConsumed == TotalBytesToConsume;
    public IEnumerable<byte> AccumulatedBytes { get; }

    public AccumulatorState ConsumeByteToNewState(byte b)
    {
        if(IsComplete)
        {
            if (IsHeaderState)
                return new AccumulatorState(ConvertHeaderToByteCount(AccumulatedBytes), 1, false, new[] { b });
            else
                return new AccumulatorState(4, 1, true, new[] { b });
        }

        return new AccumulatorState(TotalBytesToConsume, BytesConsumed + 1, IsHeaderState, AccumulatedBytes.Concat(new[] { b }));
    }

    private int ConvertHeaderToByteCount(IEnumerable<byte> bytes)
    {
        return bytes
            .Select(b => (int)b)
            .Reverse()
            .Aggregate(0, (total, i) => total * 16 + i);
    }
}
```

You can then call it like this:

```
var bytes = new byte[] { 0x0B, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x48, 0x65, 0x6C, 0x6C, 0x6F, 0x20, 0x57, 
                         0x6F, 0x72, 0x6C, 0x64, 0x12, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x54, 0x68, 0x61, 
                         0x6E, 0x6B, 0x73, 0x20, 0x66, 0x6F, 0x72, 0x20, 0x68, 0x65, 0x6C,
                         0x70, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x67 };
bytes.ToObservable()
    .Scan (new AccumulatorState(), (state, b) => state.ConsumeByteToNewState(b))
    .Where(s => s.IsComplete && !s.IsHeaderState)
    .Select(s => s.AccumulatedBytes.ToArray())
    .Dump(); //Linqpad. Switch to a .Subscribe(a => {}) if you're using something else.
```

This outputs an `IObservable<byte[]>` with two outputs:

```
48 65 6C 6C 6F 20 57 6F 72 6C 64 
54 68 61 6E 6B 73 20 66 6F 72 20 68 65 6C 70 69 6E 67
```

Comment: Thanks for the snippet.  It's definitely not too bad, but my gut felt like there would be a composable clean way to do it that I just wasn't thinking about or naive to.   Nice name, btw

Answer (score 0):

I thought of another solution, though I would prefer the `.Scan` based one:

```
public static class X
{
    public static IObservable<byte[]> RecurseHeaders(this IObservable<byte> source)
    {
        return source.Publish(_bytes => _bytes
                .Take(4)
                .ToArray()
                .Select(a => ConvertHeaderToByteCount(a))
                .SelectMany(count => count == 0
                    ? Observable.Empty<byte[]>()
                    : _bytes.Take(count).ToArray().Concat(_bytes.RecurseHeaders())
                )
            );
    }

    private static int ConvertHeaderToByteCount(IEnumerable<byte> bytes)
    {
        return bytes
            .Select(b => (int)b)
            .Reverse()
            .Aggregate(0, (total, i) => total * 16 + i);
    }

}
```

Calling it then is simple:

```
var bytes = new byte[] { 0x0B, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x48, 0x65, 0x6C, 0x6C, 0x6F, 0x20, 0x57, 
                         0x6F, 0x72, 0x6C, 0x64, 0x12, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x54, 0x68, 0x61, 
                         0x6E, 0x6B, 0x73, 0x20, 0x66, 0x6F, 0x72, 0x20, 0x68, 0x65, 0x6C,
                         0x70, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x67 };

var result = bytes.ToObservable()
    .RecurseHeaders();
```

This is pretty close to `Scan` broken down and re-implemented. You can implement `Scan` as follows:

```
public static class RxReimplementations
{
    //This is a functional implementation of Observable.Scan
    public static IObservable<TState> FunctionalScan<TSource, TState>(this IObservable<TSource> source, TState initialState, Func<TState, TSource, TState> f)
    {
        return source.Publish(_source => _source
            .Take(1)
            .SelectMany(item => f(initialState, item)
                .Using(newState => Observable.Return(newState)
                    .Concat(_source.FunctionalScan(newState, f))
                )
            )
        );
    }

    //A functional way to re-use a function result.
    public static U Using<T, U>(this T t, Func<T, U> f)
    {
        return f(t);
    }
}
```